# How to use getters and setters without generating a copy?

Tags: c++, getter-setter

I would like to know how to use getters and setters for a member variable which takes a lot of memory. Usualy i would do as bellow:

```
class A
{
private:
  BigObject object;
public:
  BigObject getObject() const
  {
    return object;
  }

  void setObject(const BigObject& object)
  {
    this->object = object;
  }
};
```

However this getter and setter i believe will copy the BigObject which i do not want. Is there a better way to do this?

I thought of doing it this way but i read on the internet that it's not a good idea because it can lead to a segmentation fault if used badly:

```
BigObject& getObject()
{
  return object
}
```

Comment: How would a setter work without making a copy?

Comment: Where did you read that on the internet that it would cause a segfault?  Returning a class member by reference is typically how this is done, so that advice is very surprising.

Comment: You could add a setter for moving `BigObject`s: `void setObject(BigObject&& object);` and implement a move constructor and move assignment operator in `BigObject`.

Comment: they said it would break "encapsulation". For example if i keep the reference and the objet gets deleted could cause a problem if i understood corectly. Yes thanks @ Ted Lyngmo i corrected it

Comment: getters and setters break encapsulation be exposing the internal types of your object. I would rather implement an action method on the class rather letting somebody get the internal state and put it back.

Comment: `if used badly` anything could lead to a segfault.

Comment: Why would the code that uses  (or modifies or 'foos' or 'bars' ...)  A::object data,  not also be in A?  How is that functionality not part of the encapsulation goals?  See articles about "Tell, don't ask".  IMHO, getters and setters waste your time (and ours).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(If you do not care about encapsulation in this case, meaning the `A::object` member should be modifiable by anyone without restriction, then look at [SergeyA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57515293/856199)).

Return by const reference in order to avoid copying and still maintain encapsulation (meaning the caller can't modify the member by mistake):

```
const BigObject& getObject() const
{
    return object;
}
```

If the caller actually wants a copy, they can do so easily themselves.

If you want to prevent dangling references (the segfault you mentioned) when the getter is used on a temporary, you can only return a copy when the getter is actually called on a temporary:

```
BigObject getObject() const &&
{
    return object;
}

const BigObject& getObject() const &
{
    return object;
}
```

This will return a copy when calling `getObject()` on a temporary. Alternatively, you can completely prevent calling the getter on a temporary by deleting that particular overload:

```
BigObject getObject() const && = delete;

const BigObject& getObject() const &
{
    return object;
}
```

Keep in mind that this is not a guaranteed safety net. It prevents some mistakes, but not all of them. The caller of the function should still be aware about object lifetimes.

You can also improve your setter, btw. Right now, it will always copy the object regardless how the caller passes the argument. You should take it by value instead and move it into the member:

```
void setObject(BigObject object)
{
    this->object = std::move(object);
}
```

This requires that `BigObject` is movable though. If it's not, then this will be even worse than before.

Comment: Note that although overloading the getter with the rv ref qualifier is handy way of avoiding some cases of dangling references, it doesn't prevent all of them. The user of the function must still obay the lifetime rules.

Comment: I'm not sure how your definition of `setObject` is an improvement over the original. In the original definition, the argument is taken by reference and then copied when `object` is assigned to `this->object` (though the original function mistakenly used `object = object` instead of `this->object = object`). In your definition, there's still a copy because the object is passed by value.

Comment: @jjramsey this is an improvement. The caller may move construct the argument in which case there will be no copy construction whatsoever. But they are also allowed to copy construct the argument when they need to.

Comment: @jjramsey When taking by value and then moving, this allows the caller to construct an object directly into the setter's argument, thus avoiding a copy altogether: `setObject(BigObject());` If the setter takes it by reference, then that temporary would always be needlessly copied. And as eeronika mentioned, this allows allows the caller to move an already existing object into `A` with `setObject(std::move(big_obj));` Again, no copy is performed.

Comment: Shouldn't getter be `BigObject getObject() const &&
{
    return std::move(object);
}`?

Comment: @Jarod42 That's interesting. I don't think I've ever seen this before. I'm not sure about the consequences of doing this though through all the different ways the `&&` qualified overload  can end up being called. Can you point me to more information about this?

Comment: (I did a mistake with my version as `const` should be removed) Your version copy-construct whereas mine move-construct (`getObject` could be renamed `takeObject` in my version).

Answer (score 4):

Best solution: make code of your class exactly that:

```
struct A
{
  BigObject object;
};
```

Explanation - avoid trivial setters and getters. If you find yourself putting those into your classes, expose the member directly and be done with it.

Do not ever listen to people who'd say "But what if in the future we add non-trivial logic"? I have seen more than a healthy dose of trivial setters and getters, been around for decades, and never replaced with something non-trivial.

Comment: Note that this has exactly the same problems with lack of encapsulation that returning a reference has. But indeed, when the encapsulation is not needed, this is the most convenient solution.

Comment: Agree with SergeyA about trivial getters and setters. This is C++, not java or C#, after all! Setters should be used when, for example, a value needs to be checked for validity and/or modified in the process.

Comment: I set Nikos C. coment as the answer because his answer was very complete. However i think i will implement your solution because i would like to be able to edit the BigObject. I was wondering can i use a class with a public variable BigObject or is this very bad?

Comment: @ThatGuyAgain I see nothing bad in it. There are use cases for structs as bundle of objects, where no encapsulation is necessary, and thus public date members are best choice.

Answer (score 2):

The common practice is to:

```
class A
{
public:
  // this method is const
  const& BigObject getObject() const
  {
    return object;
  }

  // this method is not const
  void setObject(const BigObject& object)
  {
    object = object;
  }
private:
  BigObject object;
};
```

If you need to get a read-only object - it's perfectly fine. Otherwise, consider changes in architecture.

An alternative would be to store a `std::shared_ptr` and return a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a copy of the member, you can return a reference to it. This way there is no need to copy the member.

> I thought of doing it this way but i read on the internet that it's not a good idea because it can lead to a segmentation fault if used badly

The solution is to not use it badly.

Returning a reference to a member is fairly common pattern and not generally discouraged. Although, for types that are fast to copy, returning a copy is generally superior when there is no need to refer to the member itself.

There is a solution that avoids both copying and breakage of encapsulation: Use a shared pointer, and return a copy of that shared pointer from the getter. However, this approach has a runtime cost and requires dynamic allocation, so it is not ideal for all use cases.

---

In case of setter, you may use move assignment instead, which is more efficient than copy assignment for some types.